# Sql total plays daily for top played songs in the last 30 days

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using mysql 10.4.13-MariaDB.

I am using this to get **top 10 played songs** today.

```
SELECT media_id, artist, title, SUM(c_play) AS total_count 
FROM table 
WHERE c_date > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY 
GROUP BY media_id media_id, artist, title 
HAVING SUM(c_play) > 0 
ORDER BY total_count DESC
LIMIT 0,10
```

this would return 10 results

```
song a (artist, title) - 22 plays
song b (artist, title) - 17 plays
song c (artist, title) - 11 plays
....
```

this works well.

I would like to get total plays daily **for top 10 played songs** in the last 30 days. So for example total plays today (for top 10 songs) was 41. Yesterday 38, the day before 56 etc...

I tried:

```
SELECT date(c_date) AS stat_day, media_id, artist, title, SUM(c_play) AS total_count 
FROM table 
WHERE c_date > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY 
GROUP BY date(c_date)
HAVING SUM(c_play) > 0 
ORDER BY stat_day DESC
LIMIT 0,10
```

but I am not getting expected results. The problem is I want to return 30 results (for each day for last 30 days) and I want to get group count of top 10 songs played.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I am using mysql in wp

Comment: Which MySQL version?

Comment: 10.4.13-MariaDB

Comment: From results I can see (using my query above) limit 10 does not limit to top 10 results any more, it selects all for each day ,and it does not return 30 results but 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a [Windowing Function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html) for this, which is a fairly recent addition to the MySql ecosystem (other databases have had them since 2012).

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT date(c_date) AS stat_day, media_id, artist, title, SUM(c_play) AS total_count 
       , row_number() over (partition by date(c_date) order by sum(c_play) desc) as 
    rn
    FROM table 
    WHERE c_date > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY 
    GROUP BY date(c_date), media_id, artist, title
    HAVING SUM(c_play) > 0 
) t
WHERE t.rn <= 10
```

If you only care about totals for the whole day, you can also do this:

```
SELECT stat_day, sum(total_count) as total_count
FROM (
    SELECT date(c_date) AS stat_day, media_id, artist, title, SUM(c_play) AS total_count 
       , row_number() over (partition by date(c_date) order by sum(c_play) desc) as 
    rn
    FROM table
    WHERE c_date > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY 
    GROUP BY date(c_date), media_id, artist, title
    HAVING SUM(c_play) > 0 
) t
WHERE t.rn <= 10
GROUP BY stat_day
ORDER BY stat_day
```

Finally, this may or may not work, depending the support for `LIMIT`+`ORDER BY` inside a subquery:

```
SELECT stat_day, sum(total_count) as total_count
FROM (
    SELECT date(c_date) AS stat_day, media_id, artist, title, SUM(c_play) AS total_count 
    FROM table
    WHERE c_date > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY 
    GROUP BY date(c_date), media_id, artist, title
    HAVING SUM(c_play) > 0 
    ORDER BY sum(c_play) DESC
    LIMIT 10
) t
GROUP BY stat_day
ORDER BY stat_day
```

---

**Update:** My first read of the question made me believe we wanted the top 10 songs from each day (a different set of 10 each day). A second look makes me understand we want the top 10 songs from the last 30 days combined (one set of 10 songs total), and to know the daily play count for each of those songs.

That will look more like this:

```
SELECT date(t2.c_date), t2.media_id, t2.artist, t2.title, SUM(t2.c_play) as Total_count
FROM (
    /* Media from last 30 days, numbered by play count */
    SELECT media_id, row_number() over (order by sum(c_play) desc) as rn
    FROM table 
    WHERE c_date > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY 
    GROUP BY media_id
    HAVING SUM(c_play) > 0 
) t
 /* Now look at the play data again from this time period for these same songs */
INNER JOIN table t2 ON t2.media_id = t.media_id
    AND t2.c_date > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY 
WHERE t.rn <= 10 /* Restrict to top 10 songs */
/* and group by day this time */
GROUP BY date(t2.c_date), t2.media_id, t2.artist, t2.title
```

Depending on your version of MariaDB/MySql and their configuration, you *might* be able to put he `ORDER BY` + `LIMIT 10` back into the inner query, instead of `row_number()` + `AND t.rn <= 10` as shown, and it *might* run faster. But this should work regardless, as long as Windowing Functions are supported.

Comment: Yes, but there is only one table. Your query works with 2 tables now?

Comment: @Toniq It's the same table, referenced twice in the query. That's why we use table aliases. Joining a table to itself is a perfectly fine thing to do, and is needed quite often (though it blew my mind, too, the first time I saw it back 2004-ish).

Comment: GROUP BY needs to go after WHERE, but query still doesnt work, in fact, now it even doesnt select top 10 but all, and it doesnt group by date. Can this be done with multiple queries? (without Windowing Function).

Comment: Windowing functions are available as of MariaDB 10.2, so you should have them. What is the error?

Comment: I have corrected error. But It doesnt select correct results and it doesnt group by date.

Comment: To troubleshoot, start by looking at the inner query by itself. Play counts and days aside, do the `media_id` values for rows 1 through 10 refer to the correct songs?

Comment: No, previous query did select correct songs, but still didnt group by date.

Comment: Not worried about grouping by date yet. We'll get to that. Right now I just want to know whether the inner portion of the query is doing it's job to number the correct 10 songs from the last 30 days with rows 1 through 10.

Comment: No, it doesnt select correct songs.

Comment: Okay. Remember, we're looking at the `rn` field for values 1-10, and these values might not be in the first 10 rows of the query.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you are asking. If I just run inner query, it doesnt contain all media id for required top 10 songs.

Comment: My expectation is the inner query will return rows for ALL songs played in the last 30 days, with an `rn` field telling where each of those songs ranks over that time period. I want to know the right songs are listed 1 to 10 for the `rn` column.

Comment: I [wrote a program](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8OCeyg) to generate some sample data, and then used that data to [create a db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=31eb579c15d66585085205dd7a12bebd), so we can get on the same page.

Comment: If you scroll past the long list of sample records, you'll see a result set showing the top 10 records for the period. Do you understand this query, and what it's doing?

Comment: My first read of the question made me believe we wanted the top 10 songs from each day (a different set of 10 each day). Yes, it needs to get top 10 played songs each day, (their total). So probably different set of 10 each day, unless user listens same songs :)

Comment: In that case, the first query in the answer should meet your needs.

Comment: but first query doesnt group total by date.

Comment: The first query _does_ group the total by date.

Comment: This is what I get, total counts are not combined for each date:  https://snipboard.io/2KOmju.jpg

Comment: The image fails to load, but when I [run the db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=4bb98b4cae838be54442a270ea14431d) I see totals for each song within each day.

Comment: Maybe because  my field is `c_date` date, while you have datetime?

Comment: If you only care about totals for the whole day, you can remove the song information and add another group by (I added code for that in my answer).

Comment: Yes, now I get desired results. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Is there a way to check if row_number() is supported in sql?

Comment: It's supported in MySql 8.0 and later, MariaDB 10.2 and later, and most every competitor since 2012.

Comment: Would this query be hard to do for mysql 5.7?

Comment: I'm not sure. If that MySql installation can use LIMIT in a subquery, then it could be modified for that. Otherwise it is still possible, but it's much harder.

Comment: Can you make an example with limit?

Comment: It's in the answer.

Comment: I get Reference total_count; not supported (reference to group function)] SELECT stat_day, sum(total_count) as total_count

Comment: Oops, there was a typo. It's fixed now.